# Databricks does not show matplotlib 3.2.2 figure, but instead shows: <Figure size ...x... with 1 Axes>

Tags: python, matplotlib, databricks

As stated in the title, when I use below code I don't get a figure, but I see: `<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes> [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f7df9afca50>]`

Code to reproduce behavior:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
```

I found similar questions on SO, all with the answer to use `plt.show()`, but that doesn't work.

My configuration:

- Databricks Runtime version: 7.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12)
- `matplotlib==3.3.2`

[As stated by Databricks themselves](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/matplotlib.html), from version 6.5 and up, you no longer need to use `%matplotlib inline`. Whether I use that or not, it doesn't matter since I get the same output (no figure, but the axes statement).

Note: with `matplotlib==3.2.1` I do see the figure, but I would like to know why it fails with version 3.2.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just ran into the same problem, and while this is probably too late to help you, I'm posting the solution for others. By simply adding `display()`, the visualization rendered correctly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
display()
```